# Comprehensive list of synonyms for reduce

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, functional-programming, fold

The higher order function typically known as `reduce` has a lot of synonyms in various languages.

Off the top of my head I can think of:

- `foldr`, `foldl` (a.k.a right fold and left fold) (Haskell)
- `inject` (Smalltalk, Ruby, Groovy)
- `Aggregate` (LINQ)
- `accumulate` ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29))
- `compress` ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29))

Is there a comprehensive list of all the different names this function has? If not, let's make one here. It would be useful to know.

I'm not too interested in getting the library function names from each language, I'm looking for more of a colloquial, "how is it used in a sentence" type reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All right, so far the total list seems to be:

- `catamorphism` (General term, [see Kristopher's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10875647/224354))
- `reduce` (Python, Clojure, Common Lisp, Ruby)
- `reduction` (APL)
- `foldr`, `foldl` (a.k.a right fold and left fold) (Haskell, Scheme)
- `inject` (Smalltalk, Ruby, Groovy)
- `#inject:into` (Smalltalk)
- `Aggregate` (LINQ)
- `accumulate` ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)))
- `compress` ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)))
- `insertion` (FP)
- `Insert` (J)

Thanks for the help everyone, and if someone comes by later with a better list I'll make sure to accept that one instead!

Comment: APL's Reduce (/) was renamed Insert in J (http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d420.htm). One incentive for said renaming is that Insert can produce results that do not involve reduction. Some notes on the history of this operator occur in "A Personal View of APL" (http://www.jsoftware.com/papers/APLPersonalView.htm)

Answer (score 7):

You might note that in general, this concept is known as a *catamorphism*.  [From wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism), or also the cute article [Functional programming with Bananas, Lenses, Envelopes and Barbed Wire](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.41.125).

Comment: Holy crap, I knew Erik Meijer was awesome, but I didn't know he was awesome back in 1991 too! Thanks for these :)

Answer (score 5):

From "[A tutorial on the universality and expressiveness of fold](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/fold.pdf)":

> The fold operator has its origins in recursion theory (Kleene, 1952),
>   while the use of fold as a central concept in a programming language
>   dates back to the **reduction** operator of APL (Iverson, 1962), and later
>   to the **insertion** operator of FP ([Backus, 1978](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~crary/819-f09/Backus78.pdf)).

Comment: Excellent, looks like `reduce` really is the original term.

Answer (score 2):

A couple more:

- `foldr, foldl` (Scheme)
- `reduce` (Python, Clojure, Common Lisp)
- `#inject:into:` (Smalltalk)

Answer (score 2):

Scala calls them `foldLeft` and `foldRight`. They are also represented by symbols `/:` and `:\`.

There are variations of these that do not take a seed. They are known as `reduceLeft` and `reduceRight`. There are again variations of these `reduce*` that do not throw error on an empty sequence. They're called `reduceLeftOption` and `reduceRightOption`.

There are variations where the direction of traversal doesn't matter either way. They are called `fold` and `reduce`; first takes a seed, second doesn't.

I could have put this in a nice table. Pity stackoverflow won't allow that.

Answer (score 0):

Another one

- foldl' (Haskell, like foldl, but works on longer lists)

(Hope your irony detector was on ....)